# std::wcout will not print after certain amounts of characters

Tags: c++, file

I've been beating my head against a wall with this one for a while. I'm only trying to make a simple application to read out the contents of a file. Here's some of the code:

```
errno_t error;
if ((error = fopen_s(&f, file, "r")) == 0) {
    while (true) {
        std::wcout << std::endl << "NEW RUN" << std::endl;
        wchar_t content[4096];
        if (fgetswc(content, 4096, f) == 4096) {
            std::wcout << content;
            std::wcout.flush();
        }
        else {
            std::wcout << content;
            std::wcout.flush();
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    std::wcout << "PLEASE PRINT THIS NOW";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And the custom fgetswc function:

```
int fgetswc(wchar_t buffer[], int count, FILE * f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1) {
        wchar_t c = fgetwc(f);
        if (c != WEOF) {
            buffer[i] = c;
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

It reads the first 4096 bytes out of the file, but then subsequent `std::wcout` calls will not print out to the console I have. It reads the rest of the file and ends successfully, as I can see using breakpoints and the debugger. `content` gets filled up every iteration. I also attempted putting in debug statements, but even those don't get printed. Am I just doing something wrong? As far as I can tell there's no special characters in my file, it's just a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::wcout << content;
```

This is effectively calling `std::wostream::operator<<(const wchar_t *)`. It doesn't know that `content` is not a ␀-terminated string. In fact, it can't possibly know that it has valid length 4096 in the first case and some amount less in the second case (you don't save the return value of `fgetswc`).

Comment: I wasn't aware `std::wcout` needed to be terminated by a newline, since I can just perform `std::wcout << "great";` Without any `std::endl`. I figured it'd just run through the char array, and continue on. I still don't understand why it doesn't continue, seeing as I know the first run through definitely has 4096 characters.

Comment: @duper51 The syntax `"great"` results in a 6-element array of characters, which includes a terminating NUL. How do you expect `std::wcout <<` to know where to stop printing otherwise? If you pass it a `wstring` then it has a known length, if you pass it a `wchar_t *` it depends on finding a NUL character.

Comment: @duper51: *"needed to be terminated by a newline"* - not by a newline, by the null character, which ephemient so aptly chose to represent with a ␤ symbol. And `std::endl` is not just a synonym for a newline character. It performs more than that and should usually not be used.

Comment: @ChristianHackl `s/␤/␀/` applied to the answer, my mistake for using the wrong symbol.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm aware it also flushes the buffer to the output stream, initially I was concerned that it was not flushing, so I spammed endl everywhere to try and solve two birds with one stone.